# VBA getelementsbyclassname use with getelementsbyid

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a short VBA code to click on a button on a website by searching first by its classname, and then by id:

```
Sub Autoclick[enter image description here][1]()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/"
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.getElementsByClassname("nav mainnavs").getElementById("nav-jobs").Click

End Sub
```

However the code would not click on the Jobs button. I understand that I can just use getelementbyid directly, but I'd still like to know why using getelementsbyclassname and getelementbyid together would not work.

Attached image contains the html code of the website.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You need to specify the index of the Element Collection. getElementsByClassName returns multiple elements by virtue of it's name, these multiple records get returned in a Collection. To specify which element you want you can do the following. IE.Document.getElementsByClassname("nav mainnavs")(0). The (0) part means, return the first element. Combining it together, you can do this: IE.Document.getElementsByClassname("nav mainnavs").getElementById("nav-jobs").Click.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd still like to know why using getelementsbyclassname and
>   getelementbyid together would not work.

Because code `IE.Document.getElementsByClassname("nav mainnavs").getElementById("nav-jobs")` causes error 438: *object doesn't support this property or method*.

---

It doesn't work because `getElementsByClassName("nav mainnavs")` returns a `div` and divs doesn't have any `getElementById` method.

To search the `div` by element id it would probably be necessary to loop through all the elements of it and check their id:

```
Dim mainnavs
Set mainnavs = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("nav mainnavs")

If mainnavs.Length > 0 Then
    Dim mainnavItem ' this is a div element and it doesn't have .getElementById() method
    Set mainnavItem = mainnavs.Item(0) 

    Dim itm
    For Each itm In mainnavItem.all
        If itm.ID = "nav-jobs" Then
            itm.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next itm
Else
    MsgBox "getElementsByClassName('nav mainnavs') didn't return any elements"
End If
```

[image]

> when I apply the same method to my company's website it keeps on
>   showing the message box "didn't return any elements"

This means that element with such class name does not exist on the page.

Do you wait until the page is fully loaded?

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
```

> why would we do mainnavItem.all in the For loop

This is because there is no other possibility to search for element by its id. Therefore we go through all the children of the `mainnavItem` and check the id.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer! I tried and the code works perfectly on stackoverflow.com, but when I apply the same method to my company's website it keeps on showing the message box "didn't return any elements". Also I was wondering, setting mainnavItem = mainnavs.Item(0) would make mainnavItem the first thing in the mainnavs collection of elements, but then why would we do mainnavItem.all in the For loop?